What kind of colors are good to use on a whiteboard for a colorblind student?
Basically, what are the 'ideal' colors to reduce the impact on colorblind students? Is there a good set of colors that help many (or all) colorblind students differenciate ?

Perhaps relevant: https://jfly.uni-koeln.de/color/

This is so specific that you might best ask the student itself: there are lots of different types of colourblindness, so I guess it's not possible to make a general statement here.

Colour-blindness comes in many forms, at least one of which precludes any differentiation by colour at all (seeing ‘in black and white’ only) — so there's no possible set of colours that will help all students.  For accessibility, any information presented by colour should also be presented in some other way as well.  (E.g. clearly differentiating by brightness too, or by dotted and dashed lines, or by adding symbols, or something else.  — That can help students with standard colour vision too, of course.)

@mdewey if I draw 2 functions on the coordinate plane, you want to know for sure if they are |x| and -|x| or x and -x.

@mdewey Surely it's straightforward to recognize that's it's much easier to use three different colors to draw something than to try to hand-draw three types of dashed lines or something.

How are your figures so complex that black on white won't do? In ancient times (1970s) white (chalk) on black or green got us by. This is a serious question before I could provide an answer, not a joke.

@Buffy Colored chalk had been around since forever...

You might look into tools to emulate colour blindness on a PC, and apply those to photos of your typical whiteboard work.  ColorOracle is a cross-platform (Java) desktop visualisation tool, and G'MIC (usually used as a plugin to GIMP) can produce images to save.  And that's just free software (otherwise reduce to greyscale by desaturating in any image editor of your choice).

@Buffy there's a difference between "impossible to portray in B&W" and "possible to do in B&W, but would look clearer in colour"

That's such an important Question, every educational jurisdiction should have clear and specific guidelines not just for 'a colorblind student' but for every recognised kind of colour-blindness.
Are you saying your local education authority has no such guidelines?

In my red-green colorblind experience, the most important advice I can give is to use multiple means of distinguishing visual data. Do not rely on only color.

If you want to use dots of different colors to distinguish between sets (e.g., scatter plots, vertices of graphs), then make the dots different shapes as well: circles, triangles, squares, diamonds, crosses, etc.
If you're drawing lines of different colors, draw them in different styles: solid, dashed, dotted, dash-dotted, wavy, etc.
If you need to fill in areas with different colors, vary the brightness of the color: dark red and bright green, for example. Or, use different styles of shading: solid, vertically striped, horizontally striped, etc.

The point is to make sure that there are multiple approaches for readers to comprehend the visual data. Even if a student is not colorblind, they may have some other condition that makes the drawing styles difficult to distinguish. The students will be able to use the different colors to interpret the data.

This seems to address slides and papers, not writing on a whiteboard.

@TerryLoring I think what I wrote addresses both.

However a lot of these are easier to implement on a computer (drawing several distinct dashed or dotted lines consistently, for example).  So perhaps part of the answer is to have more complicated figures prepared in advance for projection or handouts (print the latter B&W to test).  That works for lectures, less well for tutorials.  When working through a problem on the board, IME it's likely you'll draw a curve on a graph (for example) discuss it a bit, then add another curve for comparison, so there's separation in time in a live discussion.

@TerryLoring the whiteboard in this office has both a sketch graph using solid red and dotted black lines (the black pen is also better, so the red would map to grey without colour information), and a sketched diagram in black using different hatchings.  The latter was very common in industry where a decent draughtsman could pick up any old biro and clearly sketch a fairly complex design.

Color-blindness is complicated, and comes in many forms, so it is nigh certain that there is no "magic bullet" set of colors that is going to be universally distinguishable for all students.  Indeed, there are people who don't really perceive color at all, so if you are using color in important ways, you will necessarily be excluding those students.
Instead of trying to find the right set of colors, I would suggest not using color at all as the only way of conveying meaning.  Design your lectures and plan your board work so that it works in high-contrast black-and-white.  Don't rely on different colors to convey meaning (you can use color, but don't rely on it).  Mark H has already given good advice on how to do that—I don't have much to add on that front.
However, I do think that there is a buzzword with might be helpful:  Universal Design for Learning (UDL).  In particular, you are thinking about the parts of instruction which relate to the UDL guidelines on Representation / Perception.  As with all buzzwords, there is good and bad, and there is a lot of aggrandizement on the part of CAST (the organization pushing for UDL), but I have, nevertheless, found many useful ideas in the resources provided on the linked page.  If nothing else, the UDL framework provides a useful tool for helping to evaluate the quality of instruction.

A quick anecdote:  during my masters program, I worked as a TA.  My very first teaching position was a multivariable calculus class (yes, my masters institution had graduate students teach full classes, ostensibly under the supervision of a typically laissez-faire course coordinator).  Not too far into the semester, I gave a lecture which I thought was really, really good.  I had practiced drawing figures in three dimensions on the blackboard, and had used all the colors of chalk available to me to convey the material.  I felt great when I finished the class.
And then a student walked up to me and said "Xander, I'm red-green colorblind.  I don't know what you were talking about."
We went back to my office, and I worked through the material with the student a second time, without colors, but golly, that sucked.  It felt terrible to learn that my awesome lecture was useless for at least one student.
After that lecture, the student and I talked about how to make the class more accessible, and I adjusted.  We worked together to come up with useful strategies.
I guess the point of this anecdote is the following:  you should also consider talking to your students and asking them what they need in order to be successful in your class.
